Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.media.tv/channel
Getting this exception on androidTv
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.media.tv/channel
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2189)
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2155)
**
Inserting channel**
val displayName = context.getString(R.string.name)
val appLinkIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://example.com").buildUpon().build()
    val builder = Channel.Builder()
    builder.setType(TvContractCompat.Channels.TYPE_PREVIEW)
        .setDisplayName(displayName)
        .setAppLinkIntentUri(appLinkIntentUri)

    // Insert the channel into the provider.
    val channelUri = context.contentResolver.insert(
        TvContractCompat.Channels.CONTENT_URI, builder.build().toContentValues()
    )

Issue occured place inside content resolver
val channelUri = context.contentResolver.insert
